# Location of Roots

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose one has a rectangle with sides of length $1$ and $x > 1$. Find the length of $x$ so that if one chops off a square of side length from the original rectangle, the remaining rectangle is similar to the first (Two rectangles are similar if the ratios of their sides are equal, so that one is simply a magnified version of the other). Using the above geometric relationship, find a quadratic polynomial that has $x$ as a root.

Comment: Hint: Draw a picture. We have $\frac{x-1}{1}=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Already asked. Paper sizes determination.

Answer (score 0):

Sweet! Having drawn the picture, I've got the polynomial equation to be x^2 - x - 1 = 0.

Now I need to prove  that it has a root between 1 and 2 (aka the Golden Mean).
I am prepared to use the Location of Roots Theorem by using the bisection method inductively to give me a sequence of nested intervals where I'll stop when the endpoints = [1,2]?

Is this the correct way to approach thiS?